# Disk First Aid "Disk Full Error"

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I'm trying to fix an external drive by running Disk Utility's First Aid, and it can't because of this Disk Full Error (the drive was nearly full). Is there anyway I can get around this? Get it to use another drive to use as it's temp space while fixing? The drive won't mount. Thanks!

[image: errror disk full]

Comment: Ouch! If you can't mount it, you are looking at restoring from your backup, a 3rd party repair tool (perhaps), or a disk recovery tool.

Comment: … or see if you can clone it to a bigger drive. What was the initial issue prompting you to try to repair it? What format is it?

Comment: Is there any data on the drive that you would like to retain?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've ordered a bigger drive, going to try that next. The initial issue was that it wouldn't mount. It's Apple HFS extended.

Comment: @We'llSee Yeah, I had copied a whole lot of things from old laptops on their, and was going to upload it all to Google Drive. So want the data

Comment: Ah, if it won't mount at all, you might be stuck. I'd be tempted to try Alsoft's Disk Warrior before giving up though. Or maybe better,  Disk Drill to rescue it straight to the new drive

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, I'll try that if I can't clone it